# iOS automation : how to tap button that has no id

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ios-ui-automation

I have the following items in `logElementTree` output:

```
UIAButton: rect:{{20, 427}, {41, 41}}

UIAButton: rect:{{140, 427}, {41, 41}}
```

These buttons have no identifier, no name, and are not drawn in XIB. On my automation test script I only use index (something like `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[7].tap()`)

But then, this line will not always work because index is changing. I just want to ask, if there's a way to tap this button other than using index? Please note that the button has no name, so I cannot use `buttons()["name'"].tap()`

Comment: Why can't you just give it a name or an index programmatically?

Comment: @JackLawrence Can you give me example on how to do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this would be the best way to go about doing what you would like, so I'll leave it here for other developers who see this question. In your case since you have limited technical experience, I would recommend asking your developer to assign ids or names to buttons. Providing good names for buttons and other UI elements means that your app is also accessible for those users with impaired eyesight, since voiceover will read them the names you've given to your buttons. The following block of code will programmatically assign a label and a accessibility hint to a dynamically created object that conforms to `UIAccessibility`.

From Apple's documentation (in this case they're doing it on a view, but you could do it on any object like a button):

```
- (id)init
{
  _view = [[[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
  [_view setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];

  [_view setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitButton];
  [_view setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"view.label", nil)];
  [_view setAccessibilityHint:NSLocalizedString(@"view.hint", nil)];
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5

**Javascript "hack"** (not very clean, but it works...):

```
var window = UIATarget.localTarget(); 
window.tap({x:yourXCoordinateHere , y:yourYCoordinateHere});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not really good at programming, I'm a tester who likes to try automation, so your answer is quite not clear to me. I only want to know if there's a way to tap a button (no id/name) rather than using index. Thanks again.

Comment: From your answer I'm assuming that you mean you'd rather stay on the side of some javascript, correct? I'll update my answer accordingly.